# how to handle transactions in sqlite spanning multiple java methods

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Suppose I have 3 java classes : `A`, `B` and `C`. Each of these have `insert()`, `delete()` and `update()` methods. I would like to execute `A.delete()`, `B.insert()` and `C.update()` within a single transaction in a fragment. The problem is that these methods open their own instances of `SQLiteDatabase` and execute a SQL command which is automatically and immediately committed. An example method would be :

```
class A{
    ...     
    public void insert(...){
        LocalDBHelper localDBHelper = new LocalDBHelper(getActivity()); //extends SQLiteOpenHelper
        SQLiteDatabase db = localDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(...);
        localDBHelper.close();
    }
}
```

An obvious solution would be to do `getWritableDatabase()` in the fragment, then do `db.beginTransaction()` and then pass the db object to all these methods, so that all SQL commands are executed on the same db instance. Finally i can run `db.endTransaction` in the fragment.

Is there a better way?

Another solution is using interfaces( http://www.codepond.org/posts/the-right-way-to-persist-data-in-android-sqlite-database), which is pretty convoluted and i see no particular advantage of implementing it.